# ASP ListView Multiple Style

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, listview

I'm having trouble with asp ListView. I have [Message] Table which include status field = read or unread,

can listview provide different style to show this different such as,

```
if(Message.Status == "unread")
    {
       div background color = "yellow"
    }
else if (Message.Status == "read")
    {
       div background color = "Grey"
    }
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found somewhere in this site.. but forgot to bookmark it..

```
protected void ListInbox_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Panel PanelMsg;
        PanelMsg = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("PanelMsg");

        ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        string status = (string)DataBinder.Eval(dataItem.DataItem, "Status");
        if (status == "unread")
        {
            PanelMsg.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
        }
    }
```

thanks to DJ Kraze for the support..

Answer (score 2):

[listview tips and tricks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500643.aspx)

Take a look at his site

Comment: thank you kraze,, thats just what ive looking for,,  it is hard for me to understand :(

Comment: Ill try to read it again and see the files,, it's quite advance programming.. thanks again Mr. Kraze.. I'll contact u for the progress.. :)

Comment: We are advanced developers so I am quite sure that we would be able to understand.. post your progress when you get a chance..